# Ubuntu 10.04 Windows2003 adding a route for GPO assignment

Tags: windows, ubuntu, alias, routing

I want the PC's that receive IP from my Ubuntu DHCP3-server to be able to retrieve the GPOs that are on my windows 2003 server.

I'm using virtualbox and 3 virtual machines:

1. 1 windows 2003 server `192.168.0.2` with 1 NIC (internal network).
2. 1 ubuntu server 10.04 lts `192.168.0.1` with 1 NIC (internal network) and 3 aliases `192.168.21.0`, `192.168.22.0`, `192.168.100.0`
3. 1 Windows XP machine with  3 NIC's (internal network).

Answer (score 1):

The most common scenario would be to use the DNS provided by the Windows domain controller and to configure the DHCP server to offer leases that instruct the client to use the Windows server as its DNS server.

When the XP machine attempts to join the Active Directory domain it will make use of the DNS on the on the Windows server to find the local domain controller(s), among other things. Once the XP machine has successfully joined the domain and been rebooted it will automatically pick up Group Policy configuration.

You will need to add the following option to your DHCP server config in order to do this.

```
option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.2
```

Comment: I have that added already, but i can't ping windows 2k3 ( 192.168.0.2) from the pcs that are recieving ip from ubuntu.